# Installation of Hue on Apache Hadoop and Hive (Redhat)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I have a running Hadoop 2.7 and Hive 2.0.1. I am trying to install Hive editor so that I can easily write HiveQL queries. Hence, I downloaded and built Hue 3.10. I configure it to work with HDFS and Hive (I am not sure they are correct). When I launch Hue, it checks configuration and I see some errors related webhdfs in server logs of Hue

```
[27/Jul/2016 23:08:55 -0700] webhdfs      ERROR    Failed to determine superuser of WebHdfs athttp://40.221.1.44:50070/webhdfs/v1/: <HTML><HEAD>

.....
.....
[27/Jul/2016 23:10:10 -0700] webhdfs      INFO     WebHdfs at http://40.221.1.44:50070/webhdfs/v1/ -- Validation error: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">document.location.href="http://fr0-proxy-vip.eu.ab.corp/error/page.php?id=tcp_error&proxy=fr0-proxylan-p01&summary=Network Error&url=40.221.1.44&category=none&user=&ip=40.221.1.44&details=A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out""</script>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url='http://fr0-proxy-vip.eu.ab.corp/error/page.php?id=tcp_error&proxy=fr0-proxylan-p01&summary=Network Error&url=40.221.1.44&category=none&user=&ip=40.221.1.44&details=A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"'">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact the Service Desk (8666).
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
(error 503)
```

I have below information in my hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

I do not mind about other apps but really concerned with Hadoop and Hive. Any help wll be greatly appreciated.

hdfs-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
     <property>
       <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
       <value>true</value>
     </property>
   </configuration>
```

My core-site.xml

```
    <property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.baamarna5617.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.baamarna5617.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
```

I have installed hadoop as user baamarna5617.

When I launch hue browser, I created an user account with this name 'baamarna5617'. I have created /user/baamarna5617 in my hdfs.

In my mapred-site.xml, I have included the below lines

```
<property>
  <name>jobtracker.thrift.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:9290</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.jobtracker.plugins</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.ThriftJobTrackerPlugin</value>
          <description>Comma-separated list of jobtracker plug-ins to be activated.</description>
          </property>
```

And in my https-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>httpfs.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>httpfs.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
        </property>
```

My hive-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hive.hwi.listen.host</name>
  <value>40.221.1.44</value>
 </property>   

 <property>
   <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
   <value>http</value>
 </property>


 <property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
  <value>40.221.1.44</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name></name>
  <value>http</value>
 </property>


 <property>
   <name>hive.server2.webui.host</name>
   <value>40.221.1.44</value>
 </property>

  <property>
   <name>hive.server2.webui.port</name>
   <value>10002</value>
 </property>


 <property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
  <value>10001</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
  <value>cliservice</value>
 </property>

<property>
   <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
   <value>10000</value>
 </property>


 <property>
   <name>hive.metastore.thrift.framed.transport.enabled</name>
   <value>true</value>
 </property>


 <property>
   <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
   <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
 </property>
```

Now more information:-

I am working behing the network proxy

I could not successfully create a directory using webhdfs. I can list the hdfs directory and read a file but renaming a file and creation of a directory in hdfs fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with curl. I upgraded and removed all proxies set, and it started working. Thanks.